# What service(s) can be used to monitor frontend performance?

Tags: performance, monitoring, frontend

There are already plenty of hosted services for tracking server response times but we're looking for something to track page render/load times (i.e. browser renderer).

The problem with [PageSpeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/), [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/), etc is they're on request where we want something that runs constantly and takes a reading every 15 mins for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Latest browsers have a [window.performance.timing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/API/navigationTiming) property which contains the timestamp at which some events occurred (such as domainLookupStart, domLoading, domInteractive, ...).

You may want to send a sample of those numbers to your servers.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/API/navigationTiming

---

Google Analytics has a [page speed metric](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/05/measure-page-load-time-with-site-speed.html), you may want to look at it too.

Comment: Thanks- I hadn't seen that new GA metric.

Answer (score 1):

[Atatus](https://www.atatus.com/) monitors page load time and there by does Real User Monitoring (RUM), and also it monitors for JavaScript errors along with capturing all the user actions that lead to the error.

It also gives various views of how your performance is across geographical locations and browsers.

https://www.atatus.com/

https://www.atatus.com/blog/announcing-real-user-monitoring/

Disclaimer: I’m a web developer at Atatus.

Answer (score 0):

We use [GTmetrix](http://gtmetrix.com/) to get daily Page Speed and YSlow scores. If you need a higher frequency, you can automate YSlow or Page Speed using [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [ShowSlow](http://www.showslow.org/Main_Page).

Comment: Thanks but these don't give true page render/load times based upon factors such as javascript execution, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try a free tool like dynaTrace's AJAX Edition 3.  From the website: "Speed your page load times, optimize rendering, tune DOM execution, and compare to competition. Even integrate with Selenium, Watir or QTP to begin automating your performance tests. It's free, it's easy and it's now for both Firefox and IE."

I do work for dynaTrace, in full disclosure.  But this simple, free tool should be very useful to you.

Best

GP